# Disable vertical scrolling (but not horizontal) on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a web page that uses a horizontal layout. On mobile devices, I want horizontal to be the only scrollable direction, so that users can not move the page up or down.

At the moment, users can scroll down to see black emptiness, which is what I'd like to prevent.

The page is [cosmicatlas.ajread.com/timeline.html](http://cosmicatlas.ajread.com/timeline.html).

Answer (score 4):

use this css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
       max-height: 100vh;
       overflow-y: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working on iphone 13, 2532×1170 pixels

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
   body{
     overflow-y: hidden;
   }
}
```

this `@media` help to work within its CSS upto the screen width of 480px i.e normal mobile screen and `overflow-y: hidden` to disable vertical scroll

Answer (score 1):

you can set `overflow-y: hidden;` in your css. this will disable scrolling vertically